# Remove Error Message From TextFeild While User Enters/Fixes Data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build a Sign In page with Flutter. I have used a validator to validate user inputs. I am trying to remove the error message automatically when the user fixes his input. As an example, if the user enters his email as: `name@server` (missing `.domain`) and clicks continue, s/he will get an error telling the user this is not a valid email form. if the user adds the missing part, `.c (or more characters)` the error message should disappear without the need to click continue again. This should go for the password field too.
Here is my code:

```
class _SignFormState extends State<SignForm> {
  bool _isHidden = true;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  void inContact(TapDownDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _isHidden = false;
    });
  }

  void outContact(TapUpDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _isHidden = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailForm(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          buildPasswordForm(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: 'Continue',
            press: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                return;
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildPasswordForm() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
      obscureText: _isHidden,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //labelText: 'Passowrd',
        hintText: 'Password',
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.lock_sharp,
          //color: kTextColor,
        ),
        suffixIcon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(12),
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: inContact,
            onTapUp: outContact,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.remove_red_eye,
              size: 26,
              //color: kTextColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailForm() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //labelText: 'Email',
        hintText: 'Enter your email',
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return kEmailNullError;
        }
        if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          return kInvalidEmailError;
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (value) {},
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` to remove the error after enters/fixes data

```
TextFormField(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction, // <-- add this line 
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: true, ...
```